# How to access PrintSettings from c# using GeckoFX

Tags: c#, geckofx

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/Embedding_Mozilla/FAQ/How_do_I...#How_do_I_print_a_page.3F)
I need to
Query the web browser object for nsIWebBrowserPrint. 
Call the nsIWebBrowserPrint::Print() method supplying a print settings object 
(e.g. that returned from nsIWebBrowserPrint::GetGlobalPrintSettings)

However:

```
nsIWebBrowserPrint prt = myBrowser as Gecko.nsIWebBrowserPrint;
```

returns 0

while:

```
nsIWebBrowserPrint ip = Xpcom.GetInterface<nsIWebBrowserPrint>(myBrowser);
```

throws an exception (value cannot be null)

Using Geckofx 29 and xulrunner 29

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var print = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIWebBrowserPrint>(_browser.Window.DomWindow);
```

In case it's helpful to you, here is how you can go on to get the print settings:

```
var service = Xpcom.GetService<nsIPrintSettingsService>("@mozilla.org/gfx/printsettings-service;1");
var printSettings = service.GetNewPrintSettingsAttribute();
```